# How to Generate Plain Old Java Objects from following dynamic JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, pojo

I need to Generate **POJO** from **JSON** using **retrofit2** in android, but the problem is tag is changing from time to time by providing different queries.

**JSON 1**

```
{ "query":{
      "pages":{
         "4803":{
            "pageid":4803,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"hello",
            "extract":"Greating to some one"
  }}}}
```

**JSON 2**

```
{ "query":{
      "pages":{
         "2354":{
            "pageid":2354,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Nice",
            "extract":"Say Appreciation to someone"
  }}}}
```

In above 2 JSONs value is changing eg **4803** and **2354** similary I don't know in advacned all values, so how to generate POJO for that I tried a lot on [**JSONtoPOJO**](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), But its creates classes in the name of **_4803** and **_2354** but actually value changed by providing different query to API.

Here is my All Java code
**1.**

```
public class Example {
    @SerializedName("query")
    @Expose
    private Query query;

    public Query getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
public class modelClass {
    @SerializedName("pageid")
    @Expose
    private Integer pageid;
    @SerializedName("ns")
    @Expose
    private Integer ns;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("extract")
    @Expose
    private String extract;

    public Integer getPageid() {
        return pageid;
    }

    public void setPageid(Integer pageid) {
        this.pageid = pageid;
    }

    public Integer getNs() {
        return ns;
    }

    public void setNs(Integer ns) {
        this.ns = ns;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getExtract() {
        return extract;
    }

    public void setExtract(String extract) {
        this.extract = extract;
    }
}
```

**3.**

```
public class Pages {
    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, modelClass> page;

    public Map<String, modelClass> getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Map<String, modelClass> page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

**5.**

```
public class Query {

    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private Pages pages;

    public Pages getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(Pages pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

**6. Call from mainActivity** but return nullpointerException so how to extact value response.

```
ApiService apiService = RetroClient.getApiService();
        Call<Example> call = apiService.getWordList(//here i passed value, that return json//);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                 // how get json value here
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

Please tell me how to resolve such an issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Map in case of the dynamic key. For example

```
 @SerializedName("pages")
@Expose
private Map<String, yourmodelclassforinsidedynamickeyvalue> page;
```

where **yourmodelclassforinsidedynamickeyvalue** is your model class for

```
"pageid":2354,
"ns":0,
"title":"Nice",
"extract":"Say Appreciation to someone"
```

After that from map value you can get your model class. if you need key you can get that from map key.

Comment: Error is resolved but the issue on calling its return null value please check my updated question @Amit

Answer (score 0):

while using dynamic tag then you need to use hashMap

like

```
public class Pages {
    @SerializedName("pageid")
    @Expose
    private Integer pageid;
    @SerializedName("ns")
    @Expose
    private Integer ns;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("extract")
    @Expose
    private String extract;
//....
}
```

then in your response use this

```
  if (response.body() != null) {
     Example numberResponse = response.body();
     String keys = numberResponse.getQuery().getPages().toString(); 
     Map<String, Pages> entityList = 
     response.body().getQuery().getPages();
         for (String mapKey : entityList.keySet()) {
         String text = entityList.get(mapKey).getExtract();
            // use text where you want :)
   }}
```